# Force when a ring is sliding down

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A setup comprises of a metal box with a metal pole at the centre. The mass of the metal box and pole is M. A ring of mass m slides down the pole with an acceleration a. The frictional force between the ring and the pole is f. What is the force of the box on the floor when the ring is sliding down?

Intuitively I know the answer should be Mg + f. But why doesn't the weight of the ring matter?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the ring falling into the box without the pole, would the mass of the ring matter in this scenario? obviously not. Can you take it form here or should I continue?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines as well but I could not justify why friction would add to the force as without the pole the friction would also not add to the force(would it?)

Comment: The pole asserts a force $f$ on the ring, slowing it down. Now what does Newtons third law imply?

Comment: Oh I see. So because the action-reaction pair of the friction is f on the ring and -f on the pole it exerts a force but the wight does not because its pair is the gravitational attraction of the earth by the ball?

Comment: yes exactly right!